# File upload from <input type="file">

Tags: file-upload, input, angular

Using angular 2 beta, I cannot seem to get an `<input type="file">` to work.

Using diagnostic, I can see two-way binding for other `type`s such as `text`.

```
<form>
    {{diagnostic}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fileupload">Upload</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.fileupload">
    </div>
</form>
```

In my TypeScript file, I have the following diagnostic line:

```
get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model); }
```

Could it be that it is the issue of not being JSON? The value is `null`.

I cannot really verify the value of the `input`. Уven though the text next to "Choose file ..." updates, I cannot see differences in the DOM for some reason.

Comment: I did the file upload using this way. See if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43288706/3764156

Answer (score 67):

I think that it's not supported. If you have a look at this `DefaultValueAccessor` directive (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L23). You will see that the value used to update the bound element is `$event.target.value`.

This doesn't apply in the case of inputs with type `file` since the file object can be reached `$event.srcElement.files` instead.

For more details, you can have a look at this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ozZqbxIorjQW15BrDFrg?p=info:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [ UploadService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  onChange(event) {
    var files = event.srcElement.files;
    console.log(files);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is perhaps by design that the client cannot produce a JSON value for the value...

Comment: In fact, the `ngModel` can be used for something else than generating JSON ;-) Perhaps using the `files` attribute to set the value of the bound `ngModel` could be something possible... My 2 cents

Comment: onChange Event cannot recognize if same file is uploaded for the second time, with change in data.

Comment: this doesnt seem to be valid, `event` does not have a `srcElement` property

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43176930/23118) for a HTMLInputEvent type.

Answer (score 40):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input name="file" type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [ UploadService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  file: File;
  onChange(event: EventTarget) {
        let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
        let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
        let files: FileList = target.files;
        this.file = files[0];
        console.log(this.file);
    }

   doAnythingWithFile() {
   }

}
```

Answer (score 31):

There is a slightly better way to access attached files. You could use [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) to get an instance of the input element.

Here is an example based on the first answer:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="file" #file (change)="onChange(file.files)"/>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [ UploadService ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  onChange(files) {
    console.log(files);
  }
}
```

Here is an [example app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyfgta) to demonstrate this in action.

Template reference variables might be useful, e.g. you could access them via @ViewChild directly in the controller.

Comment: Hi @Belter, here is a working example which I've just made [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SSnVjpELqprZxaspAw6W?p=preview).

Which version of Ng are you using? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Hmm, I tried it with both Ng 2.4.0 and 4.3.0 (which seems you are using). You can also check [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) in the documentation. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 7):

Another way using template reference variable and ViewChild, as proposed by Frelseren:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="file" #fileInput/>
    </div>
  `
})  
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("fileInput") fileInputVariable: any;
  randomMethod() {
    const files = this.fileInputVariable.nativeElement.files;
    console.log(files);
  }
}
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40165524/4361955

Answer (score 3):

Try this small lib, works with Angular 5.0.0

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-file-upload

Quickstart example with ng2-file-upload 1.3.0:

*User clicks custom button, which triggers upload dialog from hidden input type="file" , uploading started automatically after selecting single file.*

**app.module.ts:**

```
import {FileUploadModule} from "ng2-file-upload";
```

**your.component.html:**

```
...
  <button mat-button onclick="document.getElementById('myFileInputField').click()" >
    Select and upload file
  </button>
  <input type="file" id="myFileInputField" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" style="display:none">
...
```

**your.component.ts:**

```
import {FileUploader} from 'ng2-file-upload';
...    
uploader: FileUploader;
...
constructor() {
   this.uploader = new FileUploader({url: "/your-api/some-endpoint"});
   this.uploader.onErrorItem = item => {
       console.error("Failed to upload");
       this.clearUploadField();
   };
   this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item, response) => {
       console.info("Successfully uploaded");
       this.clearUploadField();

       // (Optional) Parsing of response
       let responseObject = JSON.parse(response) as MyCustomClass;

   };

   // Asks uploader to start upload file automatically after selecting file
  this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = fileItem => this.uploader.uploadAll();
}

private clearUploadField(): void {
    (<HTMLInputElement>window.document.getElementById('myFileInputField'))
    .value = "";
}
```

Alternative lib, works in Angular 4.2.4, but requires some workarounds to adopt to Angular 5.0.0

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-http-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

If you have a complex form with multiple files and other inputs here is a solution that plays nice with `ngModel`.

It consists of a file input component that wraps a simple file input and implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface to make it consumable by `ngModel`. The component exposes the `FileList` object to `ngModel`.

This solution is based on [this](http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel) article.

The component is used like this:

```
<file-input name="file" inputId="file" [(ngModel)]="user.photo"></file-input>
<label for="file"> Select file </label>
```

Here's the component code:

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => FileInputComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'file-input',
  templateUrl: './file-input.component.html',
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class FileInputComponent {

  @Input()
  public name:string;

  @Input()
  public inputId:string;

  private innerValue:any;

  constructor() { }

  get value(): FileList {
    return this.innerValue;
  };

  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  private onChangeCallback: (_: FileList) => void = noop;

  set value(v: FileList) {
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
      this.onChangeCallback(v);
    }
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.onTouchedCallback();
  }

  writeValue(value: FileList) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  changeFile(event) {
    this.value = event.target.files;
  }
}
```

And here's the component template:

```
<input type="file" name="{{ name }}" id="{{ inputId }}" multiple="multiple" (change)="changeFile($event)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

just try `(onclick)="this.value = null"`

in your html page add onclick method to remove previous value so user can select same file again.