# How do you POST a FormData object in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, angular2-http

I need to upload a file and send some json along with it, I have this function:

```
POST_formData(url, data) {
        var headers = new Headers(), authtoken = localStorage.getItem('authtoken');

        if (authtoken) {
            headers.append("Authorization", 'Token ' + authtoken)
        }

        headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
        headers.delete("Content-Type");

        var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: this.apiURL + url,
            headers: headers,
            body: data
        })

        return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))

        .map((res: Response) => {
            if (res) {
                return { status: res.status, json: res.json() }
            }
        })
    }
```

My issue is, if I set the `content-type` to "`multipart/form-data`" my server complains about the boundaries, if I remove the `content-type` header completely, my server complains that it "`text/plain`" a supported media type.

So, how do you send FormData with angular2?

Comment: the FormData is not supported now. I can see a todo comment `// TODO: support URLSearchParams | FormData | Blob | ArrayBuffer` in `Request` class

Comment: Doing what you have now with angular 2 should work

Comment: just to note, headers.delete("Content-Type") is very important for file upload. i was doing this: headers.set("Content-Type", "") , but that will cause angular to append the multipart/form-data string with a comma(which will make it malformed. I've spent all day looking for this solution. thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's an [Open Isuue](https://github.com/angular/http/issues/75) on Angular2 Git Repository, and there is also a [Pull Request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7260) waiting to be merged, hope that it will be merged soon.

---

**Alternatively,**

You can use [**XMLHttpRequest**](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) Object directly, for that.

And don't forget to set the header

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

// IE workaround for Cache issues
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

on the `XMLHttpRequest` that you make.

---

**Similar Questions:**

[How to upload file in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985347/how-to-upload-file-in-angular2)

[Angular 2 File upload from input type=file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399617/angular-2-file-upload-from-input-type-file)

[Angular2 post uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423348/angular2-post-uploaded-file)

Comment: No longer needed to use XMLHttpRequest. It works with http

Comment: gist with example https://gist.github.com/Toxicable/1c736ed16c95bcdc7612e2c406b5ce0f

Comment: Many thanks for the link @surya, it worked like a charm!

Comment: you also might wanna check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352405/file-upload-with-angular2-to-rest-api/39862337#39862337

Comment: its not an open issue now, available in latest angular

Answer (score 29):

Template:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary">
  <input type="file" style="display: none;" multiple="true" (change)="fileChange($event)" accept=".xml">
  <span>Click Me!</span>
</label>
```

**UPD: Angular 5 - HttpClient + Typescript**

```
onFileUpload(event: EventTarget) {

  const eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext>event;
  const target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>eventObj.target;
  const files: FileList = target.files;

  const formData: FormData = new FormData();

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('file', files[i]);
  }

  // POST
  this.httpClient.post<AnalyzedData>(uploadUrl, formData).subscribe(...);
}
```

**old Http lib - before Angular 4.3**:

```
fileChange(event) {
    let files = event.target.files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        for (let file of files) {
             formData.append('files', file, file.name);
        }
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post(uploadURL, formData, options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                // Consume Files
                // ..
                console.log('uploaded and processed files');
            },
            error => console.log(error),
            () => {
                this.sleep(1000).then(() =>
                    // .. Post Upload Delayed Action
                )
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, the important line missing was:  headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

Comment: Note that this is for and old version of Http which is now (5.x) deprecated. You should use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`.

Comment: Using angular 5.2.3 and "UPD: Angular 5 - HttpClient + Typescript" solution worked for me for upload *.mp3 files. On the backend, I used Multer on NodeJS

Answer (score 5):

I know this has been marked answered and is pretty old, however I had an issue posting the FormData object to an OpenIdConnect AuthServer, and the file upload examples above weren't what I was looking for.

Here is my service that gets an OpenIdAuthToken:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http'
import { OpenIdTokenRequest, SmartData } from '../model/openid-token-request';
import { OpenIdToken } from '../model/openid-token';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class TokenService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getToken(requestData: OpenIdTokenRequest, smartData: SmartData) {
        let _urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
        _urlParams.append('code', requestData.code);
        _urlParams.append('grant_type', requestData.grantType);
        _urlParams.append('redirect_uri', requestData.redirectUri);
        _urlParams.append('client_id', requestData.clientId);

        let _url = smartData.tokenUri;
        let _options = this.getTokenPostOptions();

        return this._http.post(_url, _urlParams, _options)
            .map(response => <OpenIdToken>response.json())
    }

    private getTokenPostOptions(): RequestOptions {

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return options;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, don't need `content-type` at all.

See here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45879409/2803344

Also see here to check how to set `headers`, [Angular2 - set headers for every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request)

2017.8.25