# How to use FormData in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

*Can any one explain me how to use FormData in Typescript ?*

code:

```
  formdata: {
        prototype: FormData;
        new (user?: HTMLFormElement): FormData;
    }
```

Comment: i am not understanding how to create a FormData and send it through an http post request in angular2 which is using typescript .

Comment: You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174759/how-do-you-post-a-formdata-object-in-angular-2