# How to post data to server in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
onChange(event) {
    var image = event.srcElement.files;
    console.log(image);
```

My console value is

```
FileList {0: File, length: 1}
```

What should I send to server as my post data?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the `event.srcElement` is in fact `<input type="file">` since you're accessing it's `files` property which is [available only of file input fields](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp).

<s>Angular2 `Http` service works only with string bodies as of now. There's an opened issue to support also `FormData` which would simplify things a lot.</s>

See [feat(http): Support many types of body on Request/Response and all ConnectionBackend implementations](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2803).

Right now, you could use raw `XMLHttpRequest` object wrapped with `NgZone` to send the POST data as `FormData`.

However, maybe even easier solution for you would be to send the file as base64 encoded string:

```
onChange(event) {
    var image = event.srcElement.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (evt) => {
        // Print base64 encoded file content
        console.log(evt.target.result);
        // Send data to server
        this.http.post(url, evt.target.result)...
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
}
```

For more info see:

- [How do you POST a FormData object in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174759/how-do-you-post-a-formdata-object-in-angular-2)
- [Reading file contents on the client-side in javascript in various browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750032/reading-file-contents-on-the-client-side-in-javascript-in-various-browsers)
- http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
return this.http
      .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

is perfect, you have everything you need at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

Comment: that ok but in my case an empty object is been sent

Comment: toPromise() send an asynchronous object, so you have to protect your code until the data are actually send