# How to reset selected file with input tag file type in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

This is how my input tag looks like:

```
<input type="file" placeholder="File Name" name="filename" (change)="onChange($event)">
<button>Reset</button>
```

I want to reset the selected file in Angular 2. Help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more details.

P.S.

I could get file details from `$event` parameters and save it in a typescript variable, but this variable is not bound to the input tag.

Comment: When you say reset, what exactly do you mean. Can you create  a http://plnkr.co/ and post what problem are you facing

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can use `ViewChild` to access the input in your component. First, you need to add `#someValue` to your input so you can read it in the component:

```html
<input #myInput type="file" placeholder="File Name" name="filename" (change)="onChange($event)">
```

Then in your component you need to import `ViewChild` from `@angular/core`:

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Then you use `ViewChild` to access the input from template:

```js
@ViewChild('myInput')
myInputVariable: ElementRef;
```

Now you can use `myInputVariable` to reset the selected file because it's a reference to input with `#myInput`, for example create method `reset()` that will be called on `click` event of your button:

```js
reset() {
    console.log(this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.files);
    this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";
    console.log(this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.files);
}
```

First `console.log` will print the file you selected, second `console.log` will print an empty array because `this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";` deletes selected file(s) from the input. We have to use `this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";` to reset the value of the input because input's `FileList` attribute is **readonly**, so it is impossible to just remove item from array. Here's working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0FJ0kKCVNjUP1hGaZzTt?p=preview).

Comment: is this enough to clear value`this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";` ?/

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes, this clears selected file from file input if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: `myInputVariable` is indeed of type `ElementRef`

Comment: What if I have a variable number of "input type=file", so that the ids are dynamically generated?

Comment: in angular 8      @ViewChild('delDocModal', {static: false})delDocModal: ElementRef;

Comment: Specifying the type of the ViewChild as ElementRef<HTMLInputElement> will help you using it properly.

Answer (score 38):

I typically reset my file input after capturing the selected files. No need to push a button, you have everything required in the `$event` object that you're passing to `onChange`:

```
onChange(event) {
  // Get your files
  const files: FileList = event.target.files;

  // Clear the input
  event.target.value = null;
}
```

Different workflow, but the OP doesn't mention pushing a button is a requirement.

*UPDATED 6/14/2021 to replace `event.srcElement` with `event.target`, now that `srcElement` has been deprecated

Comment: srcElement has been deprecated.

Comment: Very nice approach. The only downside is now that user is allowed to select same file over and over again

Comment: @RodrigoBorba you can prevent that by replacing `const files` with something like `this.files` and then checking `this.files` to see if the file already exists. Really up to how you want to work with the files after getting them

Comment: You're right. But I thought it would worth to be pointed :)

Comment: `(<HTMLInputElement>target).value = null;` works for me

Answer (score 29):

**Angular 5**

**html**

```
<input type="file" #inputFile>

<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

**template**

```
@ViewChild('inputFile') myInputVariable: ElementRef;

reset() {
    this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = '';
}
```

Button is not required. You can reset it after change event, it is just for demonstration

Answer (score 16):

One way to achieve it is to wrap your input in `<form>` tag and reset it.

I'm not considering attaching thr form to `NgForm` or `FormControl` either.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-component',
  template: `
    <form #form>
      <input type="file" placeholder="File Name" name="filename">
    </form>
    <button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
`
})
class FormComponent {



  @ViewChild('form') form;


  reset() {
    this.form.nativeElement.reset()
  }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ulqh2l093LV6GlQWKkUA?p=preview

Comment: can we use `.reset()` method on viewChild ??

Comment: Hello Edmar ... can you help me out with the question on this link ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769015/filter-in-the-dropdown-not-working-with-data-from-http-get-request

Answer (score 4):

Short version [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tVfqfSzivx2LwWNGeuyI?p=preview):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <input #myInput type="file" placeholder="File Name" name="filename">
      <button (click)="myInput.value = ''">Reset</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {


}
```

And i think more common case is to not using button but do reset automatically. Angular [Template statements](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-statements) support chaining expressions so [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0ORobVa4MQRBdDjPCOqC?p=preview):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <input #myInput type="file" (change)="onChange(myInput.value, $event); myInput.value = ''" placeholder="File Name" name="filename">
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  onChange(files, event) {
    alert( files );
    alert( event.target.files[0].name );
  }

}
```

And [interesting link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672505/) about why there is no recursion on value change.

Answer (score 3):

I think its simple, use #variable

```
<input #variable type="file" placeholder="File Name" name="filename" (change)="onChange($event); variable.value='' ">
<button>Reset</button>
```

"variable.value = null" option also available

Answer (score 3):

you may use template reference variable and send to a method

html

```
<input #variable type="file" placeholder="File Name" name="filename" (change)="onChange($event, variable);">
```

component

```
onChange(event: any, element): void {
    // codes
    element.value = '';
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did it as below:

```
 <input #fileInput hidden (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)" type="file" />
 <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="fileInput.value=''; fileInput.click()"> Upload File</button>
```

I am resetting it using #fileInput in HTML rather than creating a ViewChild in component.ts .
Whenever the "Upload File" button is being clicked, first it resets the #fileInput and then triggers `#fileInput.click()` function.
If any separate button needed to reset then on click `#fileInput.value=''` can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a a very simple aproach. After a file has been uploaded, i shortly remove the input control, using *ngIf. That will cause the input field being removed from the dom and re-added, consequencely it is a new control, and therefore it is emply:

```js
showUploader: boolean = true;

async upload($event) {
  await dosomethingwiththefile();
  this.showUploader = false;
  setTimeout(() =>{ this.showUploader = true }, 100);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" (change)="upload($event)" *ngIf="showUploader">
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are facing issue with ng2-file-upload,**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" ` **#activeFrameinputFile** `ng2FileSelect [uploader]="frameUploader" (change)="frameUploader.uploadAll()" />
```

**component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('`**activeFrameinputFile**`') `**InputFrameVariable**`: ElementRef;

this.frameUploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {
    this.`**InputFrameVariable**`.nativeElement.value = '';
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="componentField" type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file">
```

component:

```
fileChange(event) {
        alert(this.torrentFileValue);
        this.torrentFileValue = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have add this input tag into form tag..

```
 <form id="form_data">
  <input  type="file" id="file_data"  name="browse"
  (change)="handleFileInput($event, dataFile, f)"  />
</form>
```

I angular typescript, I have added below lines, get your form id in document forms and make that value as null.

```
    for(let i=0; i<document.forms.length;i++){
      if(document.forms[i].length > 0){
             if(document.forms[i][0]['value']){ //document.forms[i][0] = "file_data"
                 document.forms[i][0]['value'] = "";
              }
      }
    }
```

Print document.forms in console and you can get idea..

Answer (score -1):

```html
<input type="file" id="image_control" (change)="validateFile($event)" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />
```

```
validateFile(event: any): void {
    const self = this;
    if (event.target.files.length === 1) {
      event.srcElement.value = null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you provide a short description on your code explains how it works?

Comment: As per MDN this have a poor support. For reference check this URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement @JacobNelson