# Angular 2 - File Upload - How to access file?

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular-cli

I am making a simple file upload script and have only been able to find working examples that are based off of an `input`'s `(change)` event. I.e. - https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/upload-files-to-node-js-using-angular-2/

```
<input type="file" id="userfile" class="form-control"
(change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" name='userfile'>
```

This works. And that's great.

However if I try to bind a file input to an ngModel it doesn't work.

**template**

```
<form class="form-signin" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(fileForm.value)" #fileForm="ngForm">
<input type="file" id="userfile" class="form-control"
[(ngModel)]="fileUpload.userfile" name='userfile'>
<input type="text" id="random" class="form-control"
[(ngModel)]="fileUpload.random" name="random">

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
  onSubmit(data){
    console.log("Submitted");
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Only the data set in the `random` input will show up. No files placed in the file input will show up, only as (undefined) in both my ngModel and printing out the data from `onSubmit(data)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 File upload from input type=file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399617/angular-2-file-upload-from-input-type-file)

Answer (score 2):

I also had issues with how files were handled in Angular 2, so I opted for the low-tech approach that side-steps Angular 2 forms.

My template looks like this.

```
<input class="field" type="file" (change)="setFile($event)" />
```

And to access my files, I use:

```
private setFile(event) {
    this._files = event.srcElement.files;
}
```

You can then use those files.

Keep in mind uploading multi-part file data in Angular 2 also doesn't work (last time I checked), so you may have to use manual XHR request rather than the HTTP provider. [See this answer for details about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985347/how-to-upload-file-in-angular2).