# How can I get the reference of a file through the HTML's input tag? (Angular 2)

Tags: html, angular, firebase, web

I want to upload an image in Firebase. But to do that I have to get the file first. How can I get an image of my computer, for instance, through the HTML? I'm trying to do this, but I don't know what's the return of this. Help me guys...

```
<input type="file" name="image" [(ngModel)]="myImage">
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can reference the DOM Element using `ElementRef` and then extract the data of the file uploaded  from the element reference. Use `#variableName` to reference the file input.

```
<input #fileInput (change)="fileUpload()" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

In your component class, reference the file input using `ViewChild`.

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      <input #fileInput (change)="fileUpload()" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string; 
  @ViewChild('fileInput') el:ElementRef;
  constructor(private rd: Renderer2) {
    this.name = `Angular : File Upload`
  }

  fileUpload() {
    console.log(this.el);
    // Access the uploaded file through the ElementRef
    this.uploadedFile = this.el.nativeElement.files[0]; 

  }
}
```

I have created a sample plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/N6wudgX6TkAZ7iC3NBAz/).

Comment: no need to inject viewchield. just pass the event to the change function and than acces file with event.srcElement.files[0]

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use directive with change event?

component.html

```
<input type='file' uploader accept=".txt,.doc">
```

uploader.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[uploader]'
})
export class UploaderDirective {

  @HostListener('change',['$event.target.files'])
  onChanges(files) {
    this.readFile(files[0])
  }

  readFile(file){
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = async (e: any) => {
      //DO SOMETHING HERE with e.target.result            
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(file);         
  }

}
```

Don't forget to add the Directive to your module.

Comment: this looks like a  cleaner and more re-usable solution