# NgModel on Input type file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-template

I'm trying to make a binding to an input field type file through ngModel on the typical Angular way like this:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" [(ngModel)]="file">
```

and

```
files:any
```

My problem is that after I have chosen a file, the value of my variable `files` is still `undefined`
Here an example with stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mbdww

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 File upload from input type=file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399617/angular-2-file-upload-from-input-type-file)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to do it externally through (change) event

```
<input (change)="onFileChange($event)" type="file" id="fileUpload">
```

And access in the ts file like the below code

```
  files: any[];

  onFileChange(event){
    this.files = event.target.files;
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Comment: we don't need `ngModel` in that case

Comment: i did the same but how to clear the selected file after submit ?

Comment: @Jepzen `event.target.value = null`

Comment: What if, I want to show a previously saved file. The change event on that case will not work.